# Integrate plugin in wordpress and custom wordpress administration panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering is these two options are possible:

- How to take plugin, for examples Contact 7, and integrate it into WordPress? What do I need is to make "custom wordpress administration panel" with "custom options", and I want Contact 7 to be always present, without need to install it as plugin. So, when I copy/paste my WP folder, and change wp-config.php and install theme, I want Contact 7 to be there as default.
- Is it possible to create 100% custom look for "wp-admin". If yes, can you give me some quick tips on how to do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite broad, so it will get a broad responsive from the SO WordPress community. Also, there is no short answer.

1. Yes, this is possible. But it requires strong PHP, HTML and CSS knowledge. You can implement custom plugins and widgets into your theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

2. Probably yes, but you wouldn't want to do this. It will probably we overriden by future updates to WordPress, and become a disaster to maintain. I suggest the following articles on the WP Codex. Creating Themes for the admin are fine.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes
https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form